# Using modularized route throws a 404 error

Tags: node.js, express

I'm doing to some refactoring in my application and I don't understand why this case is failing.

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const models = require('../models');
const listRoute = require('./list');

router.use('/list', listRoute);
```

list.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const models = require('../models');

const sendListDataToView = (req, res, view) => {
  // get data from backend and pass to template
}

router.route('/list/show/:id')
  .get((req, res) => {
    sendListDataToView(req, res, 'view-list')
  })

router.route('/list/expand-records-forms/:id')
  .get((req, res) => {
    sendListDataToView(req, res, 'edit-list-records')
  })

module.exports = router;
```

Trying to navigate to `/list/show/3` throws a 404 error. However, if I move the definitions of these routes and `sendListDataToView` to index.js, the page loads fine. Is this because of the multiple `router.route`s?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to wipe my original answer.

You need to create the app.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const models = require('../models');
const listRoute = require('./list');

app.use('/list', listRoute); // Using express now. 

app.listen(8080); // starts server
```

Comment: I have it like `app.use('/', index)` which leads to index.js above

Comment: I think I know what's going on, I made a bunch of mumbo-jumbo with `app` and `router` definitions and it's come to surface now